# Photoshop javascript: find saveAs options from original file?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a Photoshop javascript script which modifies an image and saves it with a new filename:

```
var newPath = originalFolder + '/' + newFileName + '.' + originalExtension;
var outFile = new File(newPath);
app.activeDocument.saveAs(outFile);
```

I can see the original file type, `app.activeDocument.fullName.type`, which turns out to be something like 'PNGf', so if I add some options to the `saveAs` call,

```
app.activeDocument.saveAs(outFile, options);
```

then I know how to construct `options`. I'd like to save the new file with the same options as the original file was saved with. For example, JPEG compression ratio, PNG compression method, `TiffSaveOptions.embedColorProfile`.

**Is it possible to discover the original save options from `app.activeDocument`?** or at least some of them?

or

**Is it possible to discover the original save options from `File.open`?**